# Non-connected Lie subgroups

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, topological-groups

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a Lie algebra and let $\mathfrak h\subset\mathfrak j$ be two subalgebras of $\mathfrak g$. Now let $G$ be a Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ and let $H$  be a  Lie 
(not necessary connected) subgroup  of $G$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak h$ and let $J$ be the connected Lie subgroup of $G$ corresponding to $\mathfrak j$.

Is it always true that $HJ:=\{hj;\ h\in H, j\in J\}$ is a Lie subgroup of $G$?

Comment: Is $HJ$ the group generated by $H$ and $J$ or is it just the subset of elements of the form $h\cdot j$ ? In that case is it even a group ?

If so, you can try to show it is a closed subgroup: as every closed subgroup of a Lie group is a Lie subgroup, then the answer would be yes.

Comment: @DIdier_ Yes I meant the subset of the elements $h\cdot j$ (I edited the question). So it is not necessary an abstract group?

Comment: @DIdier_  If $HJ$ is the group generated by $H$ and $J$ then can we say anything about its dimension in this case? i.e, Is $\dim HJ=\dim J$?

Comment: I currently have no example in mind, but I would say it is not in general a group: as $(hj)^{-1} = j^{-1}h^{-1}$, it may seem there would be no reason for $HJ$ to contain the inverse elements with no further assumptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G=SO(3)$, ${\mathfrak h}=0$, ${\mathfrak j}\cong {\mathbb R}$. Thus, $J\cong SO(2)$. As for $H$, take a randomly chosen (i.e. not normalizing $J$) finite subgroup of order 2. I leave you to check that $HJ$ is not a subgroup.